# using python looking for values in a column from a list

Tags: python, dataframe, list, indexing, row

I have a list with 3 different codes and I need to check in every row of a column from a dataframe. If every code in the list matches with the value in the dataframe column, if it does, I need to fill "YES" in a different column: (using python)

```
for l in dlist:
    for index, row in yes_marketo.iterrows():
        if row['Entry Point List'] == l:
            yes_marketo.at[index, "Marketo DEP"] = "YES"
        else:
            pass
```

But even if they don't match, it's filling with "YES"

Comment: Please provide reproducible examples of `dlist` and `yes_marketo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve it:

```
for l in dlist:
    mask = yes_marketo['Entry Point List'] == l
    yes_marketo.loc[mask, 'Marketo DEP'] = 'YES'
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can compare two rows like you did above, you may need to do some thing like this:

```
if row[0] == l[0] and row[1] == l[1] and row[2] == l[2]:
```

also you may need typecasting on some values